# How do I edit what is written in the keyboard shortcuts overlay when I press the super key in Ubuntu?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gui, source-code, notes

As the question says I want to edit what is written in the overlay when I press and hold the super key in Ubuntu. Also is it possible to include a cool image in the overlay?

Comment: you can go to settings >  devices > keyboards from there you can add keyboard shortcuts using super key, customize a command with super + key parameter there.

Comment: @Yien He wants to add his keyboard short-cuts to the help menu that appears when you long press the super / windows key.